# Why global variable is being reset in Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables

I am trying to set a variable globally and then to add values in there but it's being reset, see below;

```
class NewTestController extends Controller
{
    private $attempted = [];
    public function nextQuestion(Request $request) {
        $this->attempted[count($this->attempted)] = $request->attempted;
        dd($this->attempted);
    }
}
```

and if I use it in itself the function, it also being reset.

Comment: If you're talking about `$this->attempted`, then it's not a "global" variable; it's a property of `NewTestController`, which unless stored in session and set in `__construct()`, likely will be reset every time `nextQuestion()` is called (depending on what `nextQuestion()` is and how it works).

Comment: Thanks bro! but it's again being reset. I used this `public function __construct() { $attempted = []; }`

Comment: Well, it would be `$this->attempted = [];` in construct, not `$attempted ...` but like I said, you likely have to use some kind of session if you want it to persist between requests. I think this question is a little broad, and I'm not 100% sure what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue by making a new database as `attempted_questions` so when question is attempted so I store it into database and check that if it is there or not? The use of database is also more convenient than the use of a variable for this purpose because the database will not reset like the global variable.